# Is there a limitation of how many (process=":remote") Services in an app?

Tags: android, service

Ive been troubled I run 3 Services remotely, and seems like often times the other isnt running. while the other one is.

I read again the docs, and i still cant find it, i know that remote Services has its own heap and manage s itself but the question is, is there a limit to how many?

Dave

Comment: no there is no any limitation

Comment: add logging in _onCreate()_ / _onDestroy()_ / _onLowMemory()_. You will see what is going on. _"...the service should not be killed except in extreme low memory conditions."_